# Dask: Get scheduler address from Client

Tags: python, mpi, dask, dask-distributed, mpi4py

I'm using dask-mpi to deploy on my HPC. I'd like to get hold of the scheduler address to use with another library. This is simple in the case of a `LocalCluster` (or any other explicit cluster definition) e.g.:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)

address = cluster.scheduler_address
```

But `dask-mpi` is initialised *without* a cluster object:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_mpi import initialize

initialize()
client = Client()
```

Trying to access the underlying `client.cluster` doesn't help as, in this case, it's set to `None`.

Is there some other way to get hold of the scheduler address from the `client` or elsewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently documented (at least I couldn't find it in the [docs](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/api.html#client)), but I've found out that a `Client` object has a `scheduler` property. The address, and other properties, can be obtained like:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
address = client.scheduler.address
```

I would suppose `client.scheduler` should return a [Scheduler](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/scheduling-state.html#distributed.scheduler.Scheduler) object, but I haven't done much more digging, yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct solution and comes straight from [docs](http://mpi.dask.org/en/latest/), but one way is to specify where to write the scheduler file:

```sh
mpirun -np 4 dask-mpi --scheduler-file ~/dask-scheduler.json
```

The file will contain the connection info:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(scheduler_file='~/dask-scheduler.json')
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I suppose this would work (as a workaround), but is a bit of a pain to implement. I've found that the client can have a scheduler property, which is nicer from an API point of view.